# Issue in the date format in php and mssql

Tags: php

When i fetching data from sql server using mssql lib (freetds) and php (5.55.29) , date field is in below format

```
Oct 7 2015 07:18:55:000AM
```

, but i need the date in

```
 yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s
```

format as in sql server.

Before i had user php 5.4 on that time i get same date format as in sql server. after i changed the php version i am getting issue

whether i have to change in the settings. please help me

Thanks

Thanigaivelan

Comment: And what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I had found the solution for it.

in the php.ini we have to set

```
mssql.datetimeconvert =Off

or 

ini_set('mssql.datetimeconvert',false);
```